# How to do file I/O with std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, boolean, bit-manipulation

I need to implement a Boolean data container that will store fairly large amount of variables. I suppose I could just use `char*` and implement C-style macro accessors but I would prefer to have it wrapped in an `std::` structure. `std::bitset<size_t>` does not seem practical as it has a fixed-during-compilation size.

So that leaves me with `std::vector<bool>` which is optimized for space; and it has a nice bool-like accessor.

1. Is there a way to do something like directly feed a pointer from it to `fwrite()`?
2. And how would one do file input into such a vector?
3. And lastly, is it a good data structure when a lot of file I/O is needed?
4. What about random file access (`fseek` etc)?

EDIT: I've decided to wrap a `std::vector<unsigned int>` in a new class that has functionality demanded by my requirements.

Comment: It's a good idea - but I don't have boost deployed and I'm not sure the cost of doing that will pay off the gained benefits.

Answer (score 6):

> - Is there a way to do something like directly feed a pointer from it to fwrite()?

No, but you can do it with `std::fstream`

```
std::ofstream f("output.file");
std::copy(vb.begin(), vb.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(f, " "));
```

> - And how would one do file input into such a vector?

Using `std::fstream`

```
std::ifstream f("input.file");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<bool>(f), {}, std::back_inserter(vb));
```

> - And lastly, is it a good data structure when a lot of file I/O is needed?

No, `vector<bool>` is rarely a good data structure for any purpose. See http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html

> - What about random file access (fseek etc)?

What about it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::vector<char>`, resize it to the size of the file (or other size, say you want to process fixed length blocks), then you can pass the contents of it to a function like `fread()` or `fwrite()` in the following way:

```
std::vector<char> fileContents;
fileContents.resize(100);
fread(&fileContents[0], 1, 100, theFileStream);
```

This really just allows you to have a resizable char array, in C++ style. Perhaps it is a useful starting point? The point being that you can directly access the memory behind the vector, since it is guaranteed to be laid out sequentially, just like an array.

<strike>The same concept would work for a `std::vector<bool>` - I'd just be careful when `fread`ing into this as off the top of my head I can't tell you how big (`sizeof` wise) a `bool` is, as it depends on the platform (8bit vs 16bit vs 32bit, if you were working on a microcontroller for example).</strike>

It seems `std::vector<bool>` can be optimised to store each bool in a single bit, so, definitely do not attempt to use the memory behind a `vector<bool>` directly unless you know it is going to work!

Comment: This is a specialized version of vector, which is used for elements of type bool and optimizes for space. - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

However on the next bulletpoint it states the word "may" which may imply undefined behavior..

Comment: WOW, I did not know about that kind of optimisation in the STL... well, I'd avoid using that then. For me, use `std::vector<char>`. Unless you are dealing with GB sized files I think you should be ok, of course it all depends on many factors doesn't it.

Comment: Still, you can use the `vector<bool>` and just fill it using a loop. That isn't going to be any less efficient than using an `fread` which is likely going to use a loop also (I mean maybe it could use some magic like a shared memory page or virtual memory or something else like that, but realistically I think it would just copy the memory over which is still O(n)).

Comment: @WayneUroda In fact this wannabe-optimization is one of the biggest and oldest design-flaws of the standard library (and exactly the reason why your proposed `std::vector<char>` is far superior for file I/O (and many other things)).